# Is this backtracking approach for N Queen problem incorrect?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, c++11, c++14

The N Queen problem is behaving inappropriately i.e. it is giving some output (although incorrect) when using long long int but in case of int it is giving the board array with all the elements -1.

The code is:

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<iomanip>
  #include<cstring>

  using namespace std;
  const int d=4;

 //fills 0 to all the positions that are unsafe due to queen placed at (x,y)

  void fill(int board[d][d],int x,int y){
    for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i)
    {
      //for row and column
      board[i][y]=0; 
      board[x][i]=0;
    }
    //for the diagonal following i-1 & j-1 pattern
    for(int i=x,j=y; i>=0 && j>=0 ; --i,--j){
      board[i][j]=0;
    }
    //for the diagonal following i+1 & j+1 pattern
    for(int i=x,j=y; i<d && j<d ; ++i,++j){
      board[i][j]=0;
    } 
    //for the diagonal following i-1 & j+1 pattern
    for(int i=x,j=y; i>=0 && j<d ; --i,++j){
      board[i][j]=0;
    }
    //for the diagonal following i+1 & j-1 pattern   
    for(int i=x,j=y; i<d && j>=0 ; ++i,--j){
      board[i][j]=0;
    }    
  }


 //fills -1, i.e. clears the positions that were filled earlier due to queen at (x,y)
  void unfill(int board[d][d],int x,int y){
    for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i)
    {
      board[i][y]=-1;
      board[x][i]=-1;
    }
    for(int i=x,j=y; i>=0 && j>=0 ; --i,--j){
      board[i][j]=-1;
    }
    for(int i=x,j=y; i<d && j<d ; ++i,++j){
      board[i][j]=-1;
    } 
    for(int i=x,j=y; i>=0 && j<d ; --i,++j){
      board[i][j]=-1;
    }
    for(int i=x,j=y; i<d && j>=0 ; ++i,--j){
      board[i][j]=-1;
    } 

  }


  void printboard(int board[d][d]){
    for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < d; ++j)
      {
        cout<<setw(3)<<board[i][j]<<" ";
      }cout<<endl;
    }
  } 


  bool solve(int board[d][d],int queenno,int x,int y){
    //Returns true if all the queens are placed properly
    if(queenno==4){
      return true;
    }

    for (int i = x; i < d; ++i)
    {
      for (int j = y; j < d; ++j)
      {
        // If the position is unoccupied or safe i.e. value is -1
        if(board[i][j]==-1){
          fill(board,i,j); //assigns 0 to the places that are unsafe due to queen
          board[i][j]=1;  // places the queen at i,j
          queenno++;

          bool ans=solve(board,queenno,i,j);
          if(ans==false){
            unfill(board,i,j);  // assigns -1, i.e. backtracks
            queenno--;
            board[i][j]=-1;    // clears the earlier position of the queen
          }
        }

      }
    }
    // If can't place all the queens return false
    if(x==d-1 && y==d-1 && queenno<4){
      return false;
    }

  }



  int main()
  {
    // Creating a board of size 4x4 and assigning -1 to all its element
    int board[d][d]; 
    memset(board,-1,sizeof(board));

    bool ans=solve(board,0,0,0);
    if(ans)
      printboard(board);
    else
      cout<<"Can't print";

    return 0;
  }
```

The output(although wrong) given when using long long int is

```
  0  -1   0  -1 
  0   0   0  -1 
  1   0   0   0 
  0   0   1   0
```

Please tell where the backtracking is going wrong & also that why the program is giving no output (i.e. all the elements -1) when using int instead of long long int.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  Use a debugger and single step through your code to see where the code takes a different path than what you planned, or variables are set to values you didn't expect.

Comment: N-Queens can be solved in polynomial time. Is there a reason why you use backtracking?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I was just learning backtracking. Can you tell where the backtracking is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, your algorithm can be still much better. If you want to improve your algorithm, look at "Constraint Satisfaction Problems". Also there are places to optimize your code.

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<iomanip>
  #include<cstring>

  using namespace std;
  const int d=4;

 //fills 0 to all the positions that are unsafe due to queen placed at (x,y)

void doFill(int* x) {
    if(*x != 1) {
        *x = 0;
    }
}

  void fill(int board[d][d],int x,int y){
    for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i)
    {
      //for row and column
      doFill(&board[i][y]); 
      doFill(&board[x][i]); 
    }
    //for the diagonal following i-1 & j-1 pattern
    for(int i=x,j=y; i>=0 && j>=0 ; --i,--j){
      doFill(&board[i][j]); 
    }
    //for the diagonal following i+1 & j+1 pattern
    for(int i=x,j=y; i<d && j<d ; ++i,++j){
      doFill(&board[i][j]); 
    } 
    //for the diagonal following i-1 & j+1 pattern
    for(int i=x,j=y; i>=0 && j<d ; --i,++j){
      doFill(&board[i][j]); 
    }
    //for the diagonal following i+1 & j-1 pattern   
    for(int i=x,j=y; i<d && j>=0 ; ++i,--j){
      doFill(&board[i][j]); 
    }    
  }


 //fills -1, i.e. clears the positions that were filled earlier due to queen at (x,y)
  void unfill(int board[d][d],int x,int y){
    board[x][y] = -1;  

    for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < d; ++j) {
            if(board[i][j] != 1) {
                board[i][j] = -1;
            }
        }
    } 

  for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < d; ++j) {
            if(board[i][j] == 1) {
                fill(board, i, j);
            }
        }
    } 

  }


  void printboard(int board[d][d]){
    for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < d; ++j)
      {
        cout<<setw(3)<<board[i][j]<<" ";
      }cout<<endl;
    }
  } 


  bool solve(int board[d][d],int queenno,int y){
    //Returns true if all the queens are placed properly
    if(queenno==d){
      return true;
    }
      if(y >= d) {
          return false;
      }

  for (int j = 0; j < d; ++j)
  {
    // If the position is unoccupied or safe i.e. value is -1
    if(board[y][j]==-1){
      fill(board,y,j); //assigns 0 to the places that are unsafe due to queen
      board[y][j]=1;  // places the queen at i,j
      queenno++;
        cout << "PLACE at " << j << "," << y << endl;
        printboard(board);
        if(solve(board,queenno,y+1)) {
            return true;
        }
        cout << "BT" << endl;
        unfill(board,y,j);  // assigns -1, i.e. backtracks
        queenno--;
        printboard(board);
    }

  }

    return false;
  }



  int main()
  {
    // Creating a board of size 4x4 and assigning -1 to all its element
    int board[d][d]; 
    memset(board,-1,sizeof(board));

    bool ans=solve(board,0,0);
  if(ans) {
      cout << "RESULT:" << endl;
      printboard(board);
  }
    else
      cout<<"Can't print";

    return 0;
  }
```

Your backtracking and solving wasn't very well done. This should fix it.

Comment: The no of parameters in solve() are reduced, more specifically you have replaced (x,y) just with (y) and due to which a lot turns easier. Apart from efficient algorithm is there anything else I can learn from the parameters reduction.

Comment: Well the reason I did that was it's not necessary to search the whole board, just a next line. Beware I'm not claiming this is super efficient solution, it can be done way better.

Comment: Can you please tell that why the board array was filled with -1 in my code (please see the last lines of the question) and how the doFill() function helps.

Comment: In your backtracking, you overwrote your zeros from previous queens by -1s. My Backtracking works like that, I replace everything except queens by -1. The doFill method places 0 into given position is there is not a queen - I made that method because it was easier than putting `if` everywhere. After everything is replaced, I reconstruct the unsafe fields for every queen

Answer (score 0):

The reason, why there are `-1` in the output is a missing `return true;` at the end of the `solve`-function. Without return value, its an undefined output and so it can produce crazy results.

Comment: Well this doesn't helped:(                                                                                                           
 I think the                            if(queenno==4) return true;                          does the work